# Activate specific URL contained in an email message

Tags: vba, outlook

I know virtually nothing about VBA but am attempting to learn.  I am trying to assist a blind client who gets messages from a specific agency he uses to get freelance engagements.  These messages have to be responded to almost instantly by clicking on an "Accept" link in the message or there is no chance of getting the job.  Since he uses a screen reader this complicates matters.

I have tried to adapt what I've found at stackoverflow to take the message on receipt, triggered by a message rule, to invoke VBA code to dig out the URL and immediately activate it.

```
Sub LaunchURL(itm As MailItem)

    Dim MsgBody As String
    Dim AllMsgLines
    Dim IndividualLine
    Dim AllLineWords
    Dim SingleWord
    Dim MboxReply

    MsgBody = itm.Body
    AllMsgLines = Split(MsgBody, vbCrLf)

    For Each IndividualLine In AllMsgLines
        AllLineWords = Split(IndividualLine, " ")

        For Each SingleWord In AllLineWords
            If SingleWord Like "http://*" Then
                MboxReply = MessageBox.Show("I've found a URL", "LaunchURL Script", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                Set itm = Nothing
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next SingleWord

    Next IndividualLine 

    Set itm = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub TestLaunchURL()
    Dim currItem As MailItem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    LaunchURL currItem
End Sub
```

The code above is what I've been experimenting with.  I will actually replace the message box either with:

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" & " " & SingleWord)
```

or

```
FollowHyperlink SingleWord
```

When I run this I get "Runtime Error 91:  Object variable or With block variable not set".  I've tried stepping into the code and from what I can tell the problem originates at the SET statement in the TestLaunchURL subroutine.

I am trying to snag the message I currently have focus on in my Outlook inbox and parse it apart for the first instance of "http://", at least at the moment.

Also, what would I expect to be getting back in "SingleWord" if I have a URL that has click-through text that is shown to the user tied to the actual URL itself?  I might be able to exploit that to look for the word "Accept" just ahead of the URL itself were "Accept" the click through text.

Comment: Open an item before trying TestLaunchURL. You could if you wish switch to Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).

Comment: Thanks.  This has definitely got me moving through the code, and I figured out how to set a watch to see what values certain variables have, which I needed to do.  Would the ActiveExplorer.Selection(1) go back to the original ActiveInspector.CurrentItem if this were being triggered upon receipt of a message before the user even had a chance to touch it?  It wouldn't be the active selection in that context, but I'm not sure what syntax is appropriate in that context.  I'm trying to think ahead here.

Comment: TestLaunchURL will not be used later. It is for testing so you do not have to mail a test item to yourself.  For a true test set up a rule where the runascript option points to LaunchURL. Put a breakpoint in LaunchURL so you can step through the code and mail yourself a test item.

Comment: This may get outside the vba realm, but is still relevant, even if you can point me to the correct reference material.  I am aware that TestLaunchURL is strictly so that I can manually trigger LaunchURL.  I guess when I think of rules I'm thinking of filter rules, so I'm trying to figure out how LaunchURL would be invoked when it's really called from a rule when a message is coming in.

Comment: Google run a script outlook

Comment: Thanks.  When running through the script, SingleWord is HYPERLINK and then when the next iteration runs it is literally the following, including the actual quotation marks: "{full URL here}"BTW.  I need to separate off the actual URL between the quotation marks but cannot for the life of me figure out how to escape a double-quotation mark.  I am given an error on, WPart = Split(SingleWord, "\"").  I have found that I could use the expression, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(34), for the double-quote character, but I have to believe there is an escape mechanism for single special characters.

Comment: `debug.print "this is a quote mark character inside square brackets [""]."`   ... escape quote mark by doubling

Comment: try this to see if it would work better than processing each line. it should print the position of `http:` in the message body.   `Debug.Print InStr(1, itm.Body, "http:", vbTextCompare)`  . then do mid() function to return a chunk of text that contain the URL